# Data is not saving in the assigned data field in Access

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access

Good day again, I can't figure out why my data is saving in the wrong data field. 
Here's how it's supposed to work:
After you're done saving the data you want to assign in a Section, it should be able to save it properly to the assigned Access Database with it. 
tblAdviser has three fields: AdviserID, FacultyID, and SectionID. When you're creating a Section, it asks you which faculty would you like to handle said section. Everything about the Section is saving properly in the assigned tblSection, but it's messing up with tblAdviser (that keeps track of which Faculty is the adviser of which Section.)

I've created an ID Generator for it, and it works, but when I save the section after I'm done with it, instead of the Adviser ID Generator to save the assigned ID to the AdviserID field in tblAdviser. it instead saves the FacultyID onto AdviserID, when it's supposed to save under FacultyID data field in the tblAdviser table.

Should I include the AdviserID in just the tblSection? I tried but I haven't figured out how to not allow the program to use another faculty as an adviser if he already has one under his wing. Or is there a problem with my INSERT statement?

Let me know what's confusing, I'll try to make it clearer.

```
Private Sub AddSection(ByVal sSectionID As String, ByVal sSectionTitle As String, ByVal sYearLvl As String, ByVal sCurriculum As String, ByVal sAdviserID As String, ByVal sMaxStudent As String, _
 ByVal sCourse As String, ByVal sMajor As String)
    If SectionExistByTitle(sSectionTitle) = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Same record found...", "Duplicate Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Else
        Dim com As New OleDbCommand()
        com.CommandText = "Insert Into [Section](SectionID,SectionName,YearLvl,DepartmentID,MaxStudent,Course,Major) VALUES ('" & sSectionID & "','" & sSectionTitle & "','" & sYearLvl & "','" & sCurriculum & "','" & sMaxStudent & "','" & sCourse & "','" & sMajor & "')"
        com.Connection = clsCon.con
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim com1 As New OleDbCommand()
        com1.CommandText = "Insert Into [tblAdviser](AdviserID,FacultyID,SectionID) VALUES ('" & sAdviserID & "','" & txtFacultyID.Text & "','" & sSectionID & "')"
        com1.Connection = clsCon.con
        com1.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim pipz As New OleDbCommand("Update tblGenerator Set NextNo='" & myID & "' where TableName ='" & "Section" & "'", clsCon.con)
        pipz.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Saved...")
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub GenerateSectionID()
    Dim cmddr As New OleDbCommand("select NextNo from tblGenerator where TableName='" & "Section" & "'", clsCon.con)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmddr.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read()
        Dim strid As String = dr("NextNo").ToString()
        If strid = "" Then
            txtSectionID.Text = "SEC-" & "1"
            myID = 1
        Else
            myID = Convert.ToInt32(dr("NextNo")) + 1
            txtSectionID.Text = "SEC-" & myID.ToString()
        End If
    End While
    dr.Close()
    cmddr.Dispose()
End Sub

Public Sub GenerateAdviserID()
    Dim cmddr As New OleDbCommand("select NextNo from tblGenerator where TableName='" & "tblAdviser" & "'", clsCon.con)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmddr.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read()
        Dim strid As String = dr("NextNo").ToString()
        If strid = "" Then
            sAdviserID = "ADV-" & "1"
            myID = 1
        Else
            myID = Convert.ToInt32(dr("NextNo")) + 1
            sAdviserID = "ADV-" & myID.ToString()
        End If
    End While
    dr.Close()
    cmddr.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Is AdvisorID just the unique record identifier for tblAdvisor? If so, the code is correctly generating the next record ID and saving into AdvisorID. What you need is a way to select FacultyID from Faculty table (such as a combobox). Really should save selected FacultyID into tblSection record. If a faculty can have only 1 section at a time, there are ways to manage that.

Comment: Yes, AdvisorID is the only unique record identifier for tblAdvisor. So my code was right, but it's not working as I thought it would be? Would saving the FacultyID in the table for Secton rectify this?

Comment: That was my suggestion.

Comment: How would you propose to manage the one section under one faculty thing?

Comment: With a combobox RowSource that lists faculty not already associated with a section. This means a query something like: `SELECT ID, LastName FROM tblFaculty LEFT JOIN tblSection ON tblFaculty.ID = tblSection.FacID WHERE tblSection.FacID IS NULL;` or `SELECT ID, LastName FROM tblFaculty WHERE NOT ID IN (SELECT FacID FROM tblSection);`. Be aware this sort of conditional RowSource will have issues if used on continuous or datasheet form. If you need more help with this, start a new question.

Comment: Also, there would be other considerations for selecting advisors if you are maintaining historical data for advisor assignments.